# Errors after Upgrading from 3.0.35 > 3.041

Tags: installation, upgrades

I ran the updater from the Admin (local install.) 
After a few minutes, the update failed.

Now when I try to load the site:

```
Warning: require(C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye\wwwroot\index.php on line 20

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye\wwwroot\index.php on line 20
```

There is no `"vendor/craftcms/cms"` folder

Is there a way to manually update an existing install? I don't see that option in v3 update instructions.

Comment: you can check the file permissions once and update using composer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make sure you have [Composer installed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).

Then you can go to your project's root and run `composer update` to pull in a fresh set of dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! Had to downgrade Twig after running the updates to "2.6.2", but that got me up and going.